# Quarkus custom credential provider for mysql

Tags: encryption, passwords, quarkus

I have Quarkus application which runs as a Java service on server. It is not deployed as a Docker container image.

I've defined custom Credential provider for decrypting the mysql datasource password in my application, and not using vault storage for storing encrypted password.

I had created a credential provider and registered my credential provider classes and in the application.properties with the key  `quarkus.datasource.credentials-provider = custom`.

When I try to run the application it does not override quarkus credential provider class and gives the following error:

```
unable to find credentials provider of type default
```

Is there a way to run the application providing encrypted userid/password of mysql as a service on my prod server.

Comment: Hi, please improve your question's readability by structuring it a bit more. Note that a single line break in MarkDown between unformatted lines will be ignored and the text will become harder to read.  There are a lot of good tricks here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Also please include short code snippets of your custom provider,  application properties and anything that might be relevant.